# How to allow window function in window specification?

Tags: mariadb, mariadb-10.6

I'm trying to run this query:

```sql
SELECT uuid, 
       brainffa - LAG(brainffa, 1) OVER (ORDER BY brainffa) as brainffa 
FROM time_played 
WHERE automatic = 1 AND name LIKE 'all%' 
ORDER BY uuid DESC LIMIT 15
```

This query works fine with MySQL, but on this another db server, on MariaDB (version: `10.6.5-MariaDB-1:10.6.5+maria~bionic`) it failed with this error:

```
#4016 - Window function is not allowed in window specification
```

I searched in PhPMyAdmin for an option to allow window function, but I didn't find.

How can I allow it?

Comment: I think this might be because of the way MariaDB treats column aliases; try assigning an alias that's different from the actual column name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As Mustaccio said, the error comes from alias.

By using `as brainffa_result`, it works. Now, it's fine with MariaDB and MySQL.

My final SQL query:

```sql
SELECT uuid, 
       brainffa - LAG(brainffa, 1) OVER (ORDER BY brainffa) as brainffa_result
FROM time_played 
WHERE automatic = 1 AND name LIKE 'all%' 
ORDER BY uuid DESC LIMIT 15
```